# how initialze multi dimension variable on multi dimension set

Tags: optimization, ampl, glpk

I have a variable on these set:

```
param n=5;
param a1=4;
param u=3;
set N, default{1..n}; 
set A, default{1..a1};
set F, default{1..u}; 
set E,  within F cross N;
param Y{E,A};

I did this to initialize Y, please let me know what is my mistake?
```

Basically I first initialized set E, then Y.

```
set E:=
1  1
2  2
3  1 
3  2;

param Y:1  2  3   4 := 
1  1    1  -1  1  -1
2  2   -1  1  -1   1
3  1    1 -1  -1  -1
3  2    1 -1  -1  -1;
```

Notice that I know I can do this:

```
param Y:= 
1  1  1    1  
2  2  1   -1  
3  1  1    1 
3  2  1    1 
1  1  2   -1 
2  2  2    1 
3  1  2   -1  
3  2  2   -1  
1  1  3    1  
2  2  3   -1   
3  1  3   -1  
3  2  3   -1  
1  1  4   -1
2  2  4    1
3  1  4   -1
3  2  4   -1
```

;
But since I have 500000 rows and 40  columns it is very hard to do this format. I am looking for a matrix format as my first input.

Comment: You defined `Y` as a `vary in the `mod` file but as a `param` in the `dat` file. You can’t do both. Which do you want it to be?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 it is a param